# Serial Communications not blocking on an emulated port

Tags: c, winapi, serial-port

The below code works as expected when the communication is going through a real serial port.  The process blocks on ReadFile and waits for the serial buffer to get populated before processing continues.

However, when I connect a USB device which emulates a serial port, ReadFile will not block even when no data is going through the buffer.

Every second from a USB connected device I get the following output...

rVal=1 ch=-52 bytesRead=0

So no error is returned and bytes read is always 0 until I send bytes through the usb port.

```
DWORD rVal;
HANDLE handle;
BOOL isGood;
char Ch; //Temporary character used for reading
DWORD bytesRead;

handle = CreateFile(L "\\\\.\\COM4",          //port name
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,                 //Read/Write
    0,                                            // No Sharing
    NULL,                                         // No Security
    OPEN_EXISTING,                                // Open existing port only
    0,                                            // Non Overlapped I/O
    NULL);                                        // Null for Comm Devices

 if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
 {
     return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
 }

 isGood = SetCommMask(handle, EV_RXCHAR);
 if (isGood == false)
 {
     return USV_ERR_READER_COM;
 }

 rVal = ReadFile(handle,           //Handle of the Serial port
      &ch,       //Temporary character
      sizeof(ch),//Size of TempChar
      &bytesRead,    //Number of bytes read
      NULL);
 ...
```

Comment: I have not seen that problem on any of my, or my customers, boxes.

Comment: Do you have 4-5 crossover (CTS-RTS) connected?  If you only have 2, 3 and 7, you will need to use the xon/xoff protocol

Comment: I have no problems using a device connected to a  RS232 serial port with the above code.  The ReadFile blocks as expected until I have bytes going through the port.  When I connect a USB device, even though no bytes are going through the emulated port, ReadFile will not block.  I am puzzled.

Comment: @cup actually it is 2,3 and 5(GND) if there is no flow control...

Comment: Not sure what additional research is needed to pose a question.  I have a short sample of code I have tested with various devices, I have described the problem and described the return value.  Thanks for all that have responded.

Comment: @ArtSolano Sorry, I have no clue.  I use Win serial ports in much the same way as yourself and, no matter whether 'real' ports, or USB dongles, the read calls block until data arrives, no problem :(

Comment: @MartinJames Thanks for your input - I was responding to the down vote ... still new to this, ill keep plugging away, look for any subtle differences between emulated and real ports.  I'm using Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Sorry - I was thinking of a 25 way, not a 9 way..  It is 7-8 on a 9 way.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem was that I was not getting or setting the comm timeouts.  WinAPI for ReadFile states that this should be set and that the behavior was unpredictable if it was not set.  Now the code below works consistently across several serial devices.

```
// W32SerialLibrary.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#define SEL     4   // marks the end of the message. it should only appear after a NAK/ACK and never by itself.
#define ACK     6   // the last character before the end of the message
#define NAK     21  // the last character before the end of the message
#define GS      29  // indicates the start of a message.

#define MAX_BUFFER 512

void convertCharToWchar(const char *fromCharBuffer, wchar_t *toWcharBuffer, size_t toWcharBufferSize)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; fromCharBuffer[i] != '\0' && i < toWcharBufferSize; i++)
    {
        toWcharBuffer[i] = fromCharBuffer[i];
    }

    toWcharBuffer[i] = '\0';
}

int readMRZ(const char *portPath, char *mrzBuffer, const size_t mrzBuffer_size)
{
    HANDLE hComm;
    DCB dcbSerialParams;
    BOOL isGood;
    COMMTIMEOUTS commTimeOuts;
    char mrzChar; //Temporary character used for reading
    DWORD bytesRead;
    int mrzIndex;
    DWORD maskUsed;
    char errorChar = '_';
    wchar_t wportPath[MAX_PATH];

    convertCharToWchar(portPath, wportPath, sizeof(wportPath));

    hComm = CreateFile(wportPath,                //port name
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,                 //Read/Write
        0,                                            // No Sharing
        NULL,                                         // No Security
        OPEN_EXISTING,                                // Open existing port only
        0,                                            // Non Overlapped I/O
        NULL);                                        // Null for Comm Devices

    if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Error in opening serial port\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // setup connection

    dcbSerialParams = { 0 }; // Initializing DCB structure
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);

    isGood = GetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams);

    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_9600;  // Setting BaudRate = 9600
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;         // Setting ByteSize = 8
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;// Setting StopBits = 1
    dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;  // Setting Parity = None

                                        // setup listener

    isGood = SetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams);
    if (isGood == false)
    {
        printf("Error %d\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    GetCommTimeouts(hComm, &commTimeOuts);

    isGood = SetCommMask(hComm, EV_RXCHAR);
    if (isGood == false)
    {
        printf("Error %d\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    mrzIndex = 0;

    commTimeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
    commTimeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
    commTimeOuts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
    commTimeOuts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
    commTimeOuts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 500;

    SetCommTimeouts(hComm, &commTimeOuts);
    maskUsed = 0;
    WaitCommEvent(hComm, &maskUsed, NULL);
    commTimeOuts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 0;

    do
    {
        isGood = ReadFile(hComm,        //Handle of the Serial port
            &mrzChar,                   //Temporary character
            sizeof(mrzChar),            //Size of TempChar
            &bytesRead,                 //Number of bytes read
            NULL);

//      printf("isGood %d ch=%c dec=%d oct=%#o hex=%#08X maskUsed=%x bytesRead=%d\n", isGood, mrzChar, mrzChar, mrzChar, mrzChar, maskUsed, bytesRead);

        if (mrzChar == GS)
        {
            mrzIndex = 0;
            continue;
        }

        if (mrzChar == ACK)
        {
            mrzBuffer[mrzIndex] = '\0';
            break;
        }

        // fill buffer
        if ((mrzChar >= 48 && mrzChar <= 90) || mrzChar == '<' || mrzChar == errorChar || mrzChar == '\r')
        {
            if (mrzIndex == MAX_BUFFER)
            {
                exit(-1);
            }

            if (mrzChar == '\r')
            {
                mrzBuffer[mrzIndex++] = '\n';
            }

            mrzBuffer[mrzIndex++] = mrzChar;
        }
    }

    while (bytesRead > 0);

    CloseHandle(hComm);//Closing the Serial Port

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char mrzBuffer[512];
    int rVal;

    rVal = readMRZ("\\\\.\\COM1", mrzBuffer, sizeof(mrzBuffer));

    printf("\nrVal=%d mrzBuffer length=%d\n", rVal, strlen(mrzBuffer));
    printf("mrzBuffer=\n\"%s\"\n", mrzBuffer);
 
    return rVal;
}
```